# Two quick questions about suprmums and real functions.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset\not=X\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded set.

i) If $f$ is montone, does $\sup\limits_{x\in X}(f(x))=f(\sup(X)$? Is the dual statement for the infimum true as well?

ii) If $f$ is continuous, does $\sup\limits_{x\in X}(f(x))=f(\sup(X)$? Is the dual statement for the infimum true as well?

I can see that it is true if $f$ is continuous and increasing, but am not sure otherwise, so any help is greatly appreciated and needed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely $f$ may be monotone decreasing in either case; is this not the case?

Comment: i) Let $X=(0,1)$ and take $f(x) = x$ for $x<1$ and $f(x) = x+1$ for $x\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

For second part of your question here is are examples

(1) $X = [0,\pi]$ and $f(x) = \sin x$. Then $\sup_\limits{x\in X}f(x) = 1$ but $f(\sup X) = f(\pi) = 0$.

(2) $X = [\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ and $f(x) = \sin x$. Then $\inf_\limits{x\in X}f(x) = 0$ but $f(\inf X) = f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1$.

For the first part consider the following example

(3) $X= (0,1)$ and $
 f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   x-1 & \text{if } x \leq 0 \\
   x       & \text{if } 0<x < 1\\
x+1 & \text{if } x\geq 1
  \end{cases}.
$

Then $\sup_\limits{x\in X}f(x) = 1$ but $f(\sup X) = 2$

and

$\inf_\limits{x\in X}f(x) = 0$ but $f(\inf X) = -1$